# how I check in flask that field from form was filled by user

Tags: python, flask

I don't know how to check if user fill field in form in flask.

I have this form

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

then I want check value in field and process it.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.form['name']
    if name is None:  // this doesn't work
        # do something
    if name == string.empty: // this also doesn't work
        # do something
```

Please could you give me some advise.
Thanks

Comment: have you printed name and taken a look at what it is that request.form delivers ?

Comment: Look at `Flask-WTForms` that provide form fields rednering, form validation, security, localization. You can generate form from your model `SQLAclhemy`, `MongoEngine`.

Answer (score 16):

I see you could have two problems here, the first one is that you not specify an action attribute in your form, so first fill it with the url that will handle your form, the second
is that you are checking for `None` when an unfilled field is an empty string so you can use:

```
 name = request.form['name']
 if name == '':
      # do something
```

Alternatively if you want to fill the field with a default value when it not exists you can use `get` dict method as:

```
name = request.form.get('name', None)
if name is None:
     # do something
```

As other alternative you can use:

```
if not name:
    # do something
```

cause `''` evaluate to `False` in a boolean expression.

Comment: that's not the problem. Problem is that fields from form which is not filled by user is not '' because test if name == '' : is always false.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
     ID = request.form['ID']
           if not ID=="":
               #do stuff`
```

Comment: Consider padding out this answer to explain how it works.